# Swift how to add compiler warning to function

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a simple extension to a viewController and I would like to put a warning so that other developers don't call this function directly. I am not sure if there is an attribute that can serve this purpose in swift :

My code :

```
internal extension UIViewController {

    // add warning so that it can appear when another developer wants to directly access this function
    func removeFromParent() {

        self.willMove(toParent: nil)
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

So when another develop tries to do something like :

```
let viewController = TestViewController()
viewController.removeFromParent()
```

They should get warning that you can't use this function directly

Comment: Make it `private`

Comment: well I have one place where I am making use of the function rather filePrivate could do this better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add above your function:

```
@available(*, deprecated, message: "use `someOtherFunction` instead")
```

You could also add a commentary like this:

```
/// DEPRECATED: you should use `someOtherFunction` instead
```

So it appears when your developer use `Alt + Click`

Answer (score 4):

**Add warning->**

*Also you can use* `#error("your message")`

```
internal extension UIViewController {

    #warning("Your warning message")     
    func removeFromParent() {

        self.willMove(toParent: nil)
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

**Add warning when function called->**

```
internal extension UIViewController {

    //@available(*, unavailable)

    //@available(*, deprecated, message: "your warning message")

    //@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "new name")     

    //@available(swift, introduced: 5)
    func removeFromParent() {

        self.willMove(toParent: nil)
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

*`@available` options:*

- unavailable
- introduced
- deprecated
- obsoleted
- message
- renamed

If you need more examples please visit [hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-available-to-deprecate-old-apis)