# is it possible to create compile time warnings or erros xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is it possible create own errors and warning in xcode ?

I have a case where if any other developer use a particular function than I need to inform the user that he should wrap that function whith a particular condition.

for example if some other developer use present function of a viewcontroller, then he should need to wrap that function with if block to check some condtion before moving to next screen

```
if enableUserToMove
{
self.present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift how to add compiler warning to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263041/swift-how-to-add-compiler-warning-to-function)

Comment: Tools like SwiftLint let you create your own rules, not sure if it works in this case but it could be worth checking out.

Comment: @RajaKishan That would mean someone would have to read all the code and manually enter the warning, hardly what OP wants

Comment: thanks @JoakimDanielson, let me check swiftLint

Comment: Add a comment to the function?  If you did manage to generate a warning, it would fire all the time even if the user did conform to your conditions.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes after that we need to make somethign that the called function is wrapped in some kind of condition then warning should go away too

Answer (score 0):

```
#warning("Needs to be refactored")
// some dodgy code here


#if !canImport(UIKit)
#error("This framework requires UIKit!")
#endif
```